# Subscript out of bounds on a which statement in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
> head(newdata)
          zero       one real
601 0.01273885 0.9872611    1
602 0.01273885 0.3242234    1
```

I want to select records where one is greater than .5

When I try this, I get "subscript out of bounds." Why am I getting this error? How do I perform this select?

> newDataGoodPredict <- newdata[ which(one>0.5),]
>   Error in newdata[which(one > 0.5), ] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  For future reference, please read the [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro) FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE:

```
 # for matricies (or data.frames)
 newdata[newdata[, "one"] > 0.5, ]

 # for data.frame
 newdata[newdata$one > 0.5, ]
```

Note that you don't need `which`

---

You might have a variable in your environment named `one` which your statmenet is accessing.  The error is telling you that you are trying to index `newdata` by an invalid value

Comment: that throws "Error in newdata$one : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: @ahandler What is `class(newdata)`? If it's a matrix, you might need `newdata[which(newdata[,"one"] > 0.5),]`

Comment: @BlueMagister I am not sure what newdata was, but once I converted it to a dataframe the which code worked. If you want to answer w/this I will accept

Comment: @ahandler Might as well give the accept to this answer since it should work with data frames as well. Too bad you can't tell us what `newdata` was originally.